# How to avoid type conversion clutter in Elm SVG code

Tags: svg, types, elm

In Elm's SVG modules, all attributes seem to expect `String` type parameters, which probably makes sense from a DOM point of view. Semantically, however, many attributes are numbers, especially coordinates, radii, widths, etc, which I happen to use a lot when generating graphics algorithmically.

My understanding is that Elm does not have implicits like Scala, and that implicit conversions are frowned upon, probably for good reason.

On the other hand, I'm not willing to clutter my graphics generation code with `x <| toString <| myX`; too much visual noise.

What I do so far is define a module with functions like

```
x_ = x << toString
y_ = y << toString
```

which allows me to use `x_ myX` in the code.

Is there a more elegant solution I am not aware of?

How are others dealing with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attributes are `String` because the specifications allow for different units (px, cm, etc.)

The best approach would be to craft a series of unit helpers that help you output the right thing. `px`, `cm`, `deg`, etc.

You could have a helper that's just an alias for toString. I have used `just` as in `x (just myX)` in some CSS code I've wrote (for some reason that's how I wanted to read the code) and I've seen `s` as in `x (s myX)` (short but can be confusing).

Maybe the best is to use something like `int` as in `x (int myX)` or `float` as in `x (float myX)`

Another option that might be more elegant than `x_` is to `import Svg.Attributes as SA` and write `x = SA.x << toString`. You can also move these definitions in a module and import that instead of `Svg.Attributes`.

Comment: Aliasing `toString` with `s` is actually what I did before I went to write these `x_` etc functions. I still find it too cluttered in complex functions, especially as you need brackets or a pipe. Interesting point about the units!

Comment: Another option that might be more elegant than `x_` is to `import Svg.Attributes as SA` and  write `x = SA.x << toString`. You can also move these definitions in a module and import that instead of `Svg. Attributes`.

Comment: That's an excellent idea! I suggest that you move this from the comment to your answer, so it's more prominent for future readers. Then the checkmark is your. ;)